# Como acrescentar dois botões ao toolbar?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik

Tenho uma `grid` e gostaria de colocar dois botões na `toolbar`.

No momento estou tentando assim, mas não está dando certo:

```
toolbar: [
         {
              text: "Exportar para Excel",
              name: ["excel"]
         },
         kendo.template($("#template").html())
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui a resposta [aqui](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/toolbar/index).

Ficou assim:

```
toolbar: [
            {
                text: "Exportar para Excel",
                name: ["excel"]
            },
            {
                template: ($("#template").html())
            }

        ]
```

Agora só preciso alinhar um na esquerda e outro na direita.